# Find the fastest S3 bucket to upload to

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my mobile app, images and videos are uploaded directly to S3 and they are then accessed using CDN (Imgix for images and Cloudfront for videos).

Currently my bucket is in the US.West.1 region. Users in Asia are reporting a consistently slow upload speed. My plan is to set up another bucket in the Asian region for users closer to the Asian region to upload to.

My question is how the app can determine which bucket (region) will offer the fastest upload speed - I guess I can use the region setting but that probably wouldn't give me the most reliable information.

Cross-region replication is not optimal for me for two reasons: 1) no guarantee on when the replication will be done; and 2) incur a lot more costs (double cost in space and triple cost in transferring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this isn't to bounce around between a bunch of different S3 buckets. AWS already has a purpose built solution for this exact problem: [CloudFront uploads](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/10/15/amazon-cloudfront-now-supports-put-post-and-other-http-methods/). By uploading to CloudFront instead of S3 your users will be uploading to the closest CloudFront edge location.

Another option is to use the new [S3 Transfer Acceleration](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-storage-update-amazon-s3-transfer-acceleration-larger-snowballs-in-more-regions/) feature that was just released. This will be much easier to setup than CloudFront and will work almost exactly the same as CloudFront for file uploads to S3.

Comment: Thanks! I just found out about S3 Transfer Acceleration as well - looks exactly like what I need, even though a little bit more expensive than having different buckets. However, couldn't find any information on how to use this on iOS SDK - any guidance?

Comment: And I heard and read CloudFront uploads are not natively supported on iOS SDK yet and there are some technical challenges. Don't think they will spend much effort on this, given the new transfer acceleration functionality.

Comment: Not yet supported - Updates are here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/358